Add blur effect to element on scrollY past other div
I am trying to toggle a class on a div when the page is scrolled past another div (s1).
Whenever the page is scrolled to the specified div (s1), the class is not added to the blur div in the browser. I've tried numerous configurations of this code. This is the cleanest I've come up with but I'm unable to make it run.
The blur needs to be toggled via the 'active' class every time the top of s1 is passed, with the default being that 'active' is toggled off.
The blur itself works perfectly fine without JS logic.


var headerContainer = document.getElementById('header-container');
var blurOverlay = document.getElementById('blur--linear-gradient');
var scrolledSection = document.getElementsByClassName('s1');
var scrolledSectionPos = scrolledSection.scrollTop - headerContainer.scrollHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

    var scrollPos = window.scrollTop;

    if (scrollPos >= scrolledSectionPos) {
        blurOverlay.classList.toggle('active');
    }

});
#blur--linear-gradient {
    display: none;
}

#blur--linear-gradient.active {
    display: block;
}
<header>
    <div id="blur--linear-gradient"></div>
    <div id="header-container"></div>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="section-content s1"></div>
</main>




It seems that window.scrollTop doesn't return anything, try window.scrollY
Watch out that your 'if' is going to execute each time you reach a bigger scroll value so it's going to execute multiple times probably, try to add another var to see if you reached that before and put that in the conditions to try to handle that case
Or check if you already have that class in order to not execute DOM mutations repeatedly or toggle it unnecessarily
